# get image size inside <img> tag with object-fit

Tags: javascript, html

[image: example]

How can I get the size of an image that is already rendered on the browser, inside `<img />` tag with `object-fit: contain` property?

As you can see, `img` tag fit 100% of container, but image inside doesn't. I need size of the image, not the tag

`naturalWidth` `clientWidth` and `width` does not return the desired value

Comment: There's no `containt` only `contain`

Comment: [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186493/how-can-we-get-new-image-size-dimension-after-giving-object-fitcontain-property find solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) to get the `width` of any element

```js
function func() {
  var imgTag = document.getElementById("imgTag")
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo")
  
  demo.innerHTML = imgTag.offsetWidth

}
```

```html
<img src="https://pixy.org/src/477/4774988.jpg" width="200" height="200" id="imgTag" />
<button onclick="func()">Get width</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: i need size of image inside tag, not tag

Comment: Well up to right now there is method for size of tag only . Also when you use `object-fit`, it only change the placement of image . Like in `cover` image will span whole area , in `contain` image will maintain its aspect ratios and span according to it . You can see that by giving `background-color` to `img` tag whose size don't with `object-fit` property . Also the size remain the same where the image don't span in `contain` , you can't write or use that area . So to use that you have to reduce size of `img` tag only

Answer (score 0):

[You can use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) `window.getComputedStyle()`

```js
let para = document.querySelector('p');

let imgWithNoStyle = document.getElementById('noStyle');
let imgWithStyle = document.getElementById('withStyle');

let imgWithNoStyles = window.getComputedStyle(imgWithNoStyle);
let imgWithStyles = window.getComputedStyle(imgWithStyle);

para.textContent = `
  My computed img with no style is: 
  ${imgWithNoStyles.objectFit} 
  ${imgWithNoStyles.width} 
  ${imgWithNoStyles.height}
  and my computed img with style is: 
  ${imgWithStyles.objectFit} 
  ${imgWithStyles.width} 
  ${imgWithStyles.height}
`;
```

```css
.with-style {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" id="noStyle">

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" id="withStyle" class="with-style">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9xpgt5o6/  if change `object-fit` to `contain`, and change height to `150px`, `img.height` will return the height of the tag, not image inside

Comment: Well the image size remain the same, it(object-fit) only change the placement of image . Like  in `cover` image will span whole area , in `contain` image will maintain its aspect ratios and span according to it

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector("img").naturalWidth;
```

Comment: _"`naturalWidth` ... do **not** return the desired value"_

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 